# Multiple Child view in single Parent view

Tags: android, view

i have made two view classes

in first view class i am making more than one instance of second view

and adding into first view but it displaying only one view

please help me..

**This is Parent View**

```
package com.game.AntSmash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class surface extends LinearLayout {


    public surface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.grass));
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ant_big);
        d.setBounds(160, 0, 160 + d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        this.addView(new antView(context, d, 0.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ant_big);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            this.addView(new antView(context, d, 0.2f, 0, 0, 160, 0, 0));

    }
}
```

**This is child view**

```
package com.game.AntSmash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.BoringLayout.Metrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class antView extends View {
    int screenW = 320;
    int screenH = 480;
    int X;
    int Y;
    int initialY ;
    int ballW;
    int ballH;
    int angle;
    float dY;
    float dX;
    float acc;
    int initialX;
    Drawable ball;


    public antView(Context context, Drawable bmp, float speed, int dx, int dy, int initialX, int initialY, int angle) {
        super(context); 
        this.ball = bmp;
        this.acc = speed;
        this.dX = dx;
        this.dY = dy;
        this.initialX = initialX;
        this.initialY = initialY;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas); 

        //compute roughly ball speed and location
        Y+= (int) dY; //increase or decrease vertical position  
        if (Y > (screenH - ballH)) {
            dY=(-1)*dY; //reverse speed when bottom hit 
        }
        dY+= acc; //increase or decrease speed

        //compute roughly ball speed and location
        X+= (int) dX; //increase or decrease vertical position  
        if (X > (screenW - ballW)) {
            dX=(-1)*dX; //reverse speed when bottom hit 
        }
        dX+= acc / 5; //increase or decrease speed


        //increase rotating angle
        if ((angle = angle + 10) >360) angle =0;

        //draw ball
        canvas.save(); //save the position of the canvas
        canvas.rotate(angle, X + (ballW / 2), Y + (ballH / 2)); //rotate the canvas
        canvas.translate(X, Y);
        ball.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore(); //rotate the canvas back so that it looks like ball has rotated


        //call the next frame
        if(X > screenW - ballW && Y > screenH - ballH) {

        } else {
            invalidate();
        }

    }

}
```

**And this is activity**

```
package com.game.AntSmash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AntSmashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout v = new surface(this);
        setContentView(v);

    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of view? Show us some code and maybe your layout XML, if you use one.

Comment: I have added code see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some layout params for your LinearLayout parent, also use `setOrientation()` to define how the child views should be displayed.

The dimension of the child is probably just too big.

If you want to use 2D drawing, I recommend a [tutorial series](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series) I have written. Its easier to use a SurfaceView for 2D drawing than using Views and Layouts.

A tip at the end: A class name should start with an upper case. `Surface` and `AntView` instead of `surface` and `antView`.

Comment: If a add surface then i am not able to override OnTouchEvent for child view

Comment: @Dharmendra: I don't understand your previous comment. If you plan to write a game (I see that in the package name), than I strongly recommend my tutorial series. There you find everything you need for a basic game like "antsmash"

Comment: @WarrenFaith i refer Your Tutorial in your tutorial you are adding Bitmap on Surface touch but now i want to stop moving bitmap if i touch bitmap

Comment: @Dharmendra: If you finished the old part (the new one isn't finished right now) you should get the idea on how to do collision detection. The RockScissorPaper used basic collision detection based on the bitmaps, you just need to change that to detect a collision with your touch event. Thats all. Just do one step after another. If you have still trouble, create a new question (post the link here, so I get notified)